# Can find maven dependency on mvnrepository.com but not on repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have the following maven dependency in my POM file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
<version>16.20.00.10</version>
</dependency>
```

which I can find on mvnrepository.com [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.teradata.jdbc/terajdbc4/16.20.00.10), however when I compile I get an unresolved dependency error and in the error it says it cannot find this dependency in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 (which is true).  So I'm wondering why does this exist in mvnrepository.com but not https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2?  Which one is the real central repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that mvnrepository.com is in fact an aggregator across many repositories, not just Maven Central.

The artifact that you linked to includes a note:

> this artifact it located at ICM repository (http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/)

You can [check out](https://mvnrepository.com/repos) all of the different repositories that mvnrepository.com indexes.

To search Maven Central, use https://search.maven.org/